# How do you order rewrite rules for installing Wordrpess in a subdirectory and also forcing HTTPS?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am installing Wordpress in its own directory and also want to force HTTPS. Which comes first: the rewrite rules to force HTTPS, or the rewrite rules to direct to the subdirectory?

I have already done the force HTTPS, which works fine.

Here is how I'm forcing the HTTPS (of course "example.net" isn't the name of the site!):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.net/$1 [R,L]
```

And the code for using the subdirectory, which comes from https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/ is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_subdir/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Do I have the correct order here, or do I redirect to the subdirectory first and then force the HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which comes first: the rewrite rules to force HTTPS, or the rewrite rules to direct to the subdirectory?

The directives to force HTTPS need to go first. If you put them after the WordPress front-controller then your WordPress URLs won't be redirected (by `.htaccess` at least) - only your *static resources* (images, CSS, JS, etc.) would be redirected, which aren't handled by the WordPress front-controller.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
> ```

You have many checks for the hostname. Unless you have multiple domains (or subdomains of the main domain) that all point to the same area on the filesystem and serve a different purpose, then this is unnecessary.

Currently, your HTTP to HTTPS redirect is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Test with a 302 to avoid caching issues, but ultimately, the HTTP to HTTPS redirect should be a 301 (permanent) redirect. ie. change the `RewriteRule` flag `R` to `R=301`.

Comment: Do you mean I can delete the second hostname check, after 
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on`

For that matter, do I need to have a second `RewriteEngine on` within the `IfModule`, or is it enough to have only one such statement at the top, before the HTTPS directives?

Comment: Yes, if the user is always requesting `example.com` (or `www.example.com`) then the condition that checks the `Host` header serves no purpose. You don't need the second `RewriteEngine On` directive, although it can help with readability. (You should avoid manually editing the `.htaccess` directives inside the `# BEGIN WordPress` block - if still present.) The `RewriteEngine On` directive can actually appear anywhere in the file, it doesn't need to be at the top (although it is naturally more readable if it is).

Comment: Thank you for that clarification--I'm grateful for your assistance! One more question (which may be an obvious one): will the directives in this `IfModule` also direct the urls of individual pages to the subdirectory? For instance, if someone has a link to `example.com/news-archive` will they get to the right page even with WP in the subdirectory?

Comment: Yes, that is what those directives do. The request is rewritten to that subdirectory. The subdirectory is not part of the URL - it is hidden from the user. Presumably you also have another `.htaccess` file in the WordPress installation subdirectory with _similar_ directives that routes the request through WordPress?

Comment: Bit of an side... depending on your config you may find that the WP site is accessible by explicitly including the subdirectory in the URL - ideally this should _redirect_ to remove the subdirectory from the URL (but that is a different question).  This is less of an issue if this is a new site, since the subdirectory is not publicly known.

Comment: Regarding what you said about the redirect to remove the subdirectory from the URL, how would I do that? Would I add: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com/my_subdir$` and would I have to add a new RewriteRule? And perhaps a better question is: where do I go to learn these codes more thoroughly?

Comment: And, also in the interest of thoroughness, can you explain what you meant by `Presumably you also have another .htaccess file in the WordPress installation subdirectory with similar directives that routes the request through WordPress?`

Comment: "redirect to remove the subdirectory" - that is really a different question and should therefore be asked as another question (if it is an issue at all). (No you would not add that `RewriteCond` directive - that would likely break it. The `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains the value of the `Host` HTTP request header - this does not contain the URL-path.)

Comment: "what you meant by" - I assume your site works OK, so this is not an issue.

Comment: Thank you again--you have been most generous with your time and knowledge!